# devise - Customizing the User Edit Pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

currently with devise & rails 3 there is a one page user edit page: /users/edit

I would like to split that out into sections for a better UI, something like:

```
/account/settings
/account/password
/account/notices
/account/disable
```

Also, I'd like to require the user to enter their current password when a user wants to change their password.

With devise, to make this happen, does this require a new controller, or can this all be handled with routes?

Also, currently, the edit page lives here: app/views/devise/registrations

Do you recommend adding these pages there? Or in /app/views/users ?

Thanks

Answer (score 14):

You have multiple options here. I would go with the first option as it seems to more naturally fit what you are trying to do.

1. Override devise's registrations controller by inheriting from it, and update the corresponding views and routes. Here is what devise's [site](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) says about this:

   > **Configuring controllers**
   >
   > If the customization at the views
   >   level is not enough, you can customize
   >   each controller by following these
   >   steps:
   >
   > 1) Create your custom controller, for
   >   example a Admins::SessionsController:
   >
   > class Admins::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
   >    end
   >
   > 2) Tell the router to use this
   >   controller:
   >
   > devise_for :admins, :controllers => { :sessions => "admins/sessions" }
   >
   > 3) And since we changed the
   >   controller, it won’t use the
   >   "devise/sessions" views, so remember
   >   to copy "devise/sessions" to
   >   "admin/sessions".
   >
   > Remember that Devise uses flash
   >   messages to let users know if sign in
   >   was successful or failed. Devise
   >   expects your application to call
   >   "flash[:notice]" and "flash[:alert]"
   >   as appropriate.
2. Use the User controller and add actions there with corresponding views (not my choice)